# Summing by indexing in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

Sample data

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(Rcpp)

df <- data.frame(year = rep(2003:2004, each = 4), 
             mg = rep(rep(c("a", "b"), each = 2), times = 2),
             plant_date = c(20, 30, 20, 30, 33, 40, 33, 40),
             stage1 = c(40, 50, 42, 52, 43, 55, 48, 57),
             stage2 = c(55, 65, 57, 66, 58, 68, 59, 65),
             stage3 = c(61, 75, 63, 76, 66, 77, 68, 79))

set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(year = rep(2003:2004, each = 365), doy = rep(1:365, times = 2), 
              rainfall = sample(0:20, 730, replace = T))

final.dat <- dat %>% dplyr::left_join(df)
```

What I want to do is for each year, take a combination of `plant.date` and `mg`, and sum and mean of rainfall from `plant.date` to `stage1`, `stage1` to`stage2`and
`stage2` to `stage3`. I did this:

```
final.dat %>% dplyr::group_by(year, plant_date, mg) %>% 
dplyr::summarise(
sum_rain_stage1 = sum(rainfall[doy >= plant_date & doy <= stage1]),
sum_rain_stage2 = sum(rainfall[doy >= plant_date & doy <= stage2]),
sum_rain_stage3 = sum(rainfall[doy >= plant_date & doy <= stage3]),
mean_rain_stage1 = mean(rainfall[doy >= plant_date & doy <= stage1]),
mean_rain_stage2 = mean(rainfall[doy >= plant_date & doy <= stage2]),
mean_rain_stage3 = mean(rainfall[doy >= plant_date & doy <= stage3]))
```

I want to achieve similar using `Rcpp`. But due to lack of familiarity, I was only able to develop the skeleton of this as follows:

```
final.dat <- data.table(final.dat)   
setkey(x, year, plant_date, mg, doy)
```

Define the function (below) and source it:

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp("rainfall_sum.cpp"))
```

and run the function as follows:

```
 final.dat[, c("sum_rain_stage1","sum_rain_stage2","sum_rain_stage3" , "mean_rain_stage1", , "mean_rain_stage2", "mean_rain_stage3") := rainfall_sum(doy, rainfall, plant_date, stage1, stage2 , stage3), keyby = .(year, plant_date, mg)]
```

## My (incomplete) function is:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]

List rainfall_sum(NumericVector doy,
                  NumericVector rainfall,
                  double plant_date,
                  double stage1,
                  double stage2,
                  double stage3) {

 double sum_rain_stage1(n);
 double sum_rain_stage2(n);
 double sum_rain_stage3(n);
 double mean_rain_stage1(n);
 double mean_rain_stage2(n);
 double mean_rain_stage3(n);

  # This part I do not know how to sum/average rainfall from plant_date to stage1, stage1 to stage2 and stage2 to stage3
}

 return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("sum_rain_stage1") = sum_rain_stage1,
                      Rcpp::Named("sum_rain_stage2") = sum_rain_stage2,
                      Rcpp::Named("sum_rain_stage3") = sum_rain_stage3,
                      Rcpp::Named("mean_rain_stage1") = mean_rain_stage1,
                      Rcpp::Named("mean_rain_stage2") = mean_rain_stage2,
                      Rcpp::Named("mean_rain_stage3") = mean_rain_stage3);
 }
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this in Rcpp? Is `dplyr` not fast enough? Did you try `data.table`?

Comment: My actual data involves lot of climate variable i.e. in addition to rainfall, I have around 30 variables and instead of 2 years, I have more than 50 years. I  will have a follow up question on those but once I figure out how to do this, only then I can post the follow up question.

Comment: Downvote wasn't me. However, you answered none of my questions.

Comment: If Rcpp is a must, I would suggest creating simpler functions mean() and sum() in c++ and using likes of R's _apply() to add new cols in your data.frame.

Comment: @RalfStubner this data comes from a given location and for limited years and climate variables. I have to do similar calculation for more than 5000 locations involving 30 climate variables and 50 years. When I did this, dplyr was relatively slow. I had used Rcpp for some other work previously for other intetions and it performed way much faster than dplyr. data.table I have not actually used before.

Comment: I seriously doubt you can write C++ code that does this faster than good data.table code. I suggest reading the data.table vignettes instead of asking here for C++ code.

Comment: Adding to the comment by @Roland: `dplyr` is itself written in C++ using `Rcpp`. Doing efficient aggregations is far from trivial!

Answer (score -1):

To answer the question, here is function for summing up elements, leave as an exercise to calculate mean in c++.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double sumRcpp(NumericVector x){
  int n = x.size(); // Size of vector
  double sum = 0; // Sum value
  // For loop, note cpp index shift to 0
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    // Shorthand for sum = sum + x[i]
    sum += x[i];
  }
  return sum; // Obtain and return the Sum
}

// You can include R code blocks in C++ files processed with sourceCpp
// (useful for testing and development). The R code will be automatically 
// run after the compilation.
//

/*** R
sumRcpp(c(42,43))
*/
```

Comment: There are Rcpp sugar functions for `sum` and `mean`. The difficult part in this question is the `group_by` part.

Comment: And we all think it will hard to beat much simpler `data.table` solution.